# Configure ack on a per-directory basis

Tags: grep, ack

My goal is to not have to always tell `ack` which directories to grep in a given project (if I don't, it's slow because it scans non-source folders as well). I've so far come up with puting an executable `./ack` script in the project folder that delegates to the global ack command with some extra options, but ideally I would have something like `.ackrc` in that project directory and `ack` would just pick that up automatically.

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

ack $@ src subproj1/src subproj2/src subproj3/src
```

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636065/how-do-you-exclude-a-specific-file-from-ack-ack-grep/44838125#44838125

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ack 2.0 supports per-project .ackrc files.

Make sure that you use ack 2.12 or above because previous versions of 2.x have a security hole with those .ackrc files.

Comment: Weird thing is: explicitly passing in only the directories I want to grep in, to ack, makes ack run much much faster than using a set of `--ignore-dir=is:<dirname>` in `.ackrc`...

Comment: That makes sense.  The --ignore-dir still takes time for ack to go through the file system and examine each directory to see if it should be excluded.  Passing in only the directories you want to search eliminates that scanning.